# Python - Elegant way to transform list to list of all combinations

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list of elements like:

```
x = ['A, B', '2', '3', 'Jan, Feb']
#      ^                   ^
#    comma separated single string
```

I want to transform this list into a *list of lists* with all the combinations of each element that is comma separated so that it looks like:

```
[['A', '2', '3', 'Jan'], ['A', '2', '3', 'Feb']
 ['B', '2', '3', 'Jan'], ['B', '2', '3', 'Feb']]
```

What is the elegant way to achieve this using Python's in-built functions/libraries?

Comment: Have you made any attempts so far?

Comment: Bob, you've done a good job describing what you want to do. But [SO] isn't based on descriptions, but rather questions and answers. Do you have a specific question to ask?

Comment: Some string split  and itertools.permutations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may firstly split the elements of list based on comma `,` and then use [**`itertools.product`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#product) to get the desired list as:

```
from itertools import product
x = ['A, B', '2', '3', 'Jan, Feb']

new_list = list(product(*[i.split(', ') for i in x]))
```

where content of `new_list` will be:

```
[('A', '2', '3', 'Jan'), 
 ('A', '2', '3', 'Feb'), 
 ('B', '2', '3', 'Jan'), 
 ('B', '2', '3', 'Feb')]
```

---

Based on Dan D's comment, below is the `timeit` comparison of intermediate List V/s intermediate generator comparison on Python 2. Intermediate list expression is slightly faster:

```
mquadri$ python -m timeit "from itertools import product; list(product(*(i.split(', ') for i in ['A, B', '2', '3', 'Jan, Feb'])))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.83 usec per loop

mquadri$ python -m timeit "from itertools import product; list(product(*[i.split(', ') for i in ['A, B', '2', '3', 'Jan, Feb']]))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.78 usec per loop
```

Comment: You could avoid making a useless list by passing the generator expression to the splat: `list(product(*(i.split(', ') for i in x)))`.

Comment: @DanD. Intermediate list will be comparatively faster in this case. Reason being that the generator expression is useless here because in order to be used with *product*, it has to be completely evaluated

Comment: Editted answer with `timeit` comparison of both

Comment: Thanks a lot... Exactly what I was looking for